# can't access function with argument inside the struct

Tags: c#

I don't understand why the function `f.Display_Family(f);` doesn't show the names.

What I missed in that code?

```
namespace Field
{
    struct Person
    {
       public string name;

    }
    struct Family
    {
        public Person Father;
        public Person Mother;

        public void Create_Family()
        {
            Family f;
            Console.WriteLine("give name and family name");
            f.Father.name = Console.ReadLine();
            f.Mother.name = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public void Display_Family(Family f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Father.name);
            Console.WriteLine(f.Mother.name);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Family f = new Family();
            f.Create_Family();
            f.Display_Family(f);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rango Not really, I can tell you "this doesn't work" and "this works" in a correctly researched question

Comment: I mean the names which I entered are not showed. just empty lines. 
and I need to make it with the struck.

Comment: In  `Create_Family` you are setting the names of an instance of `Family` created within in the function, not the instance you are calling the method on

Comment: @Rango There is absolutely nothing wrong with using structs here.  Sure, a class would be better but it's a simple program so no real difference.  Lastly, the OP is obviously new to C# so your comment is very troll-like.

Comment: @Alexander should probably learn the [difference](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+class+vs+struct&oq=c%23+class+vs+struct&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.3455j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) between struct and class

Comment: @Christo: especially if you're new to C# it would be better to start with classes. But deleted the comment

Answer (score 3):

This method is wrong:

```
public void Create_Family()
{
    Family f;
    Console.WriteLine("give name and family name");
    f.Father.name = Console.ReadLine();
    f.Mother.name = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You are creating *another* family in this function, initialize it and abandon. Your original family struct is not modified!

Better would be

```
public void Create_Family()
{
    Console.WriteLine("give name and family name");
    Father.name = Console.ReadLine();
    Mother.name = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As well, the method `Display_Family` shouldn't actually take a parameter, as it can perfectly work on the current instance. Just use

```
public void Display_Family()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Father.name);
    Console.WriteLine(Mother.name);
}
```

and call it without parameter.

Good luck in your studying!

---

Besides, you ought to switch to using classes, because family is an "object with individuality": different families, albeit having the same member names, are different objects.

Comment: Thank you!! your explanation was really helpful!! n

Comment: @Alexander: Glad that it helped!